# Run simple web server with Terraform remote-exec

Tags: python-3.x, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
# example.tf
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami             = "ami-0d44833027c1a3297"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.example.name}"]
  key_name        = "${aws_key_pair.generated_key.key_name}"

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "cd /home/ubuntu/",
      "nohup python3 -m http.server 8080 &",
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      private_key = "${tls_private_key.example.private_key_pem}"
      user        = "ubuntu"
      timeout     = "1m"
    }
  }
}

resource "tls_private_key" "example" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "generated_key" {
  key_name   = "example_key_pair"
  public_key = "${tls_private_key.example.public_key_openssh}"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "example" {
  name        = "grant ssh"
  description = "grant ssh"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

`ami-0d44833027c1a3297` is an ubuntu AMI with a hello world index.html sitting at `/home/ubuntu/`

Although, I get no errors and the ec2 instance is up and running, the http server doesn't run.

Note: If I ssh manually and apply the same set of commands in the inline section, I am able to successfully run the http server. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix:

```
inline = [
      ....
      "sleep 20",
    ]
```

I believe the the provisioner exit before the server process began(race condition) and hence the sleep was necessary.

Note: got the idea of sleep from Hashicorp Packer documentation(https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/shell.html)

Comment: In my case, sleep 60 was helpful.